# Loop to Create Buttons

Tags: java, swing

I need to create two classes within a larger class. One that take info from a text file in the format:
String:double

String:double

...

and outputs the two variables.
And a second class that takes this information and loops, creating buttons with each text entry as the label.
My code so far is:

```
public class MainClass {
        Scanner readFile = new Scanner(new File("text.txt"));
        while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
           String name = readFile.next();
           double value = readFile.nextDouble();
    }
    class Button {
        Button(String text. double number) {
            this.text=text;
            this.number=number;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I go from here?

Comment: This code doesn't actually compile, does it?

Comment: Replace ":|\\n" with ":|\\\n" as letter n will be used as a delimiter.

Comment: I would suggest that you pickup a book on Java UI development. The knowledge you need is not going to fit into a stackoverflow answer.

Comment: I don't have an answer but I fixed your code (if my edit gets approved) so it would compile.

Comment: @James, looking at your other question, it is clear you have very limited knowledge of Java. Nothing wrong with that, but for Pete's sake, stay a way from Swing until you've learned some basic Java! Your question "How do I go from here?" makes it clear you're just guessing.

Comment: @StackOverflowException, that's not really what "edits" are for: to radically change someone else's code so that it compiles, that'd be better suited as an answer.

Comment: @Bart Gotcha! I'm still learning the the culture here. I learnt about spoon-feeding on homework questions the hard way the other day.

Comment: Hi James! It's worth noting that if the code from your other question worked for you, you should make sure to accept it as your answer. Also, if the other answers are helpful (even if they aren't 'the answer you're looking for') you should considering upvoting them when you get the rep for it. Upvotes and green checks are the flowers and candy of StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but here's the OP's code modified so it compiles

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class MainClass {
    class ScanFile {
        void Foo() throws FileNotFoundException{
            Scanner readFile = new Scanner(new File("text.txt")); // don't forget to catch FileNotFoundException!
            readFile.useDelimiter(":|\\n");
            while (readFile.hasNext()) {
               String name = readFile.next();
               double value = readFile.nextDouble();
               System.out.println(name + " " + value);
            }
        }
    }
    class Button extends JButton {
        String text;
        double number;
        Button(String text, double number) {
            super(text);
            this.text=text;
            this.number=number;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@James, making buttons, while not difficult, does require a working knowledge of Java (because you also have to know how to create Frames, Panels, ActionListeners, and handle Events when your buttons are clicked--enough material to fill a textbook alone!).

If you're only interested in making some buttons in a window, the following tutorials should give you an idea of how to make a rudimentary frame with buttons:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html

But to make it display exactly as you want it to (and using a loop!) is going to require a lot of thinking on your part.